# Cannot open pictures or videos in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, crash, windows-media-player, photos

A couple of days ago my laptop battery drained and shut down. After attempting to turn on, normal boot resulted in a black screen with startup sound. I then followed a guide which led me to restart in safe mode, and update video adapter from device manager. This fixed black screen. Now however, I've noticed that I cannot open any photos, or play any videos via any player (vlc, mpc-hc + k-lite, and wmp). Because there's no crash message,I can only describe the problem.

Pictures: I double click, cursor plays hourglass animation, but nothing happens.

Videos: I double click, player opens, and immediately closes.

Not sure if caused by same problem, but windows explorer crashes when attempting to open advanced display settings.

Thank you for any help. So far I've tried to Google anything I can think of, but no one appears to have solved my problem online yet. Right now I'm accessing my videos and photos from browser, but this is very frustrating.

- cheers

**EDIT**
Just noticed that screensaver isn't launching. Screen flashes black for millisecond, but returns to desktop.

**EDIT - System Information**

- Toshiba Satellite L755D
- Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium SP1
- AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
- AMD Radeon(tm) HD 6520G
- DirectX 11 / OpenGL 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have installed the wrong version of video driver or the driver for another OS; or maybe you have the new 32bit driver installed for a 64 bit OS or vice versa. So check whether that is the issue, if not, then you may revert to using your earlier version of driver.

Comment: That was my first thought, like perhaps the shutdown and updating of the adapter had corrupted the driver. But after attempting to install the newest driver (the one I had previously) the black boot screen happened again during installation. I had to start in safe mode, and run update on adapter again.

Comment: How did you update it? I would suggest getting the offline setup from the Graphic card manufacturer website or from your PC brand, and not rely on Windows.
please do check whether there is a BIOS Update and Chipset Driver Update available.
Also please post your entire PC specifications including the driver version

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where to get the full specs with driver versions. I used IOBits system information app, but it didn't give driver versions. Also, I updated the display adapter over internet, but installed graphics driver from package downloaded from AMD site.

Comment: Try [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) for system information. Do you have two different adapters as in one is integrated and other is dedicated? If the display adapter/integrated graphic card is Intel, then download offline installer for that too and install it.

Comment: I just used CPU-Z and it just gave me the same information as I posted above. No driver versions, though the driver I was attempting to install is 14.9 Catalyst. There's only one adapter entry in device manager, so I think there's only one.

Comment: What about bit version compatibility and BIOS and chipset updates?

Comment: Bit version is good, OS is 64 bit and so is driver (AMD-Catalyst-14-9-win7-win8.1-64Bit-dd-ccc-whql). BIOS is Insyde Corp, Version 1.50. BIOS and chipset versions haven't been a problem in the past.

Comment: Try reverting to the earlier version of the driver. If that doesn't work, do a system restore and then install the new driver. (Also check whether you have another Integrated graphic card in your PC apart from the dedicated AMD). You can even reinstall Windows over your existing installation without formatting if all else fails. I'm afraid I've run out of options. Good Luck buddy.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll try some of those options, and update the post.